# Programa entra em loop infinito

Tags: java, loop

Meu objetivo com o código era montar um jogo que perguntasse a pessoa qual número o computador estaria "pensando" (de 1 a 100), e conforme a pessoa dissesse um número de 1 a 100, o computador dissesse se o número randômico gerado é maior ou menor do que o que a pessoa digitou até que ela acertasse.

Porém, quando eu rodo o programa, ele entra em loop com "Adivinhe o número".

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int numSorte = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;

    System.out.println("Adivinhe o número que estou pensando,ele está entre 1 e 100");

    boolean continuar = true;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(continuar = true) {
        System.out.println("Adivinhe o número :");
    }
    int numUsuario = Integer.valueOf(scan.next());

    if(numUsuario == numSorte) {
        System.out.println("VOCÊ GANHOU!!!!!!");
        continuar = false;
    }
    else if(numUsuario < numSorte) {
        System.out.println("O número" + numUsuario + "é menor do que o número sorteado");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("O número" + numUsuario + "é maior do que o número sorteado");
    }
    scan.close();
```

Comment: Voce fechou o while com apenas esse texto num loop infinito, por isso. Mova a chave logo abaixo do `System.out.println("Adivinhe o número :");` para logo acima do `scan.close()` que rodará corretamente

Comment: caramba cara,muito obrigado mesmo,estava a um tempo quebrando a cabeça com algo tão bobo.

Comment: tá ok,sou novo aqui não sei como funciona,converte ai pra mim te dar o ✓

Comment: Esqueci de falar na outra pergunta do AP: além de aceitar a resposta, pode votar +1 nela.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Voce fechou o while com apenas o `System.out.println("Adivinhe o número :");` num loop infinito, por essa razão não sai dessa execuçao.

Mova a chave logo abaixo do `System.out.println("Adivinhe o número :");` para logo acima do `scan.close()`, de modo a envolver todo o restante do código dentro do loop que rodará corretamente:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int numSorte = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;

System.out.println("Adivinhe o número que estou pensando,ele está entre 1 e 100");

boolean continuar = true;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

while(continuar = true) {

        System.out.println("Adivinhe o número :");

    int numUsuario = Integer.valueOf(scan.next());

    if(numUsuario == numSorte) {
        System.out.println("VOCÊ GANHOU!!!!!!");
        continuar = false;
    }
    else if(numUsuario < numSorte) {
        System.out.println("O número" + numUsuario + "é menor do que o número sorteado");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("O número" + numUsuario + "é maior do que o número sorteado");
    }
    scan.close();
}
```